# Save Ajax request result in file

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to save my Ajax request result into a file

Look at my code :

```
function getAjax(id) {

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"+id,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
      $('#name').html(result.name)
      $('#email').html(result.email)
      $('#id').html(result.id)
      $('#company').html(result.company.name)
      $('#adress').html(result.address.street)
      $('#suite').html(result.address.suite)
      $('#city').html(result.address.city)
      $('#zipcode').html(result.address.zipcode)
      $('#geolatt').html(result.address.geo.lat)
      $('#geolong').html(result.address.geo.lng)
```

And here I would save the result on a file with this method:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
$line = ""; // MY DATA HERE
$file = 'visitors.log';
$oldContents = file_get_contents($file);
$fr = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($fr, "$line");
fwrite($fr, $oldContents);
fclose($fr);
```

Thanks you for help

Answer (score 0):

I would nest another ajax call to your php server.

```
function saveToServer(result)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "/somepath/somepage.php",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: { MyDatas: result },
        success: function()
        {
            //Hooray
        }
    }
}

function getAjax(id)
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"+id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(result)
        {
            saveToServer(result);
            console.log(result);
            /*
             * your code
             */
        }
    }
}
```

And then, server side, at `/somepath/somepage.php` :

```
if (isset($_POST['MyDatas']))
{
    //save to file the content of $_POST['MyDatas']
}
```